# POI / Excel : applying formulas in a "relative" way

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I'm using Apache's POI to manipulate Excel (.xls) files with Java.

I'm trying to create a new cell whom content is the result of a formula as if the user had copied/pasted the formula (what i call the "relative" way, as opposite to "absolute").

To make myself clearer, here is a simple example:

- Cell A1 contains "1",B1 contains "2", A2 contains "3", B2 contains "4".
- Cell A3 contains the following formula "=A1+B1".

If I copy the formula to the A4 cell under excel, it becomes `"=A2+B2"` : excel is adapting the content of the formula dynamically.

Unfortunately I cannot get the same result programatically. The only solution I found is to tokenize the formula and do the dirty work myself, but I really doubt that this is supposed to be done that way. I was not able to find what I'm looking for in the guides or in the API.

Is there an easier way to solve this problem ? If it's the case, can you please point me in the right direction ?

Best regards,

Nils

Answer (score 13):

In my sense, *user2622016* is right, except his solution manages only **cell** references, as opposed to **area** references (it won't work for `=SUM(A1:B8)` for instance).

Here's how I fixed this :

```
private void copyFormula(Sheet sheet, Cell org, Cell dest) {
    if (org == null || dest == null || sheet == null 
            || org.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
        return;
    if (org.isPartOfArrayFormulaGroup())
        return;
    String formula = org.getCellFormula();
    int shiftRows = dest.getRowIndex() - org.getRowIndex();
    int shiftCols = dest.getColumnIndex() - org.getColumnIndex();
    XSSFEvaluationWorkbook workbookWrapper = 
            XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((XSSFWorkbook) sheet.getWorkbook());
    Ptg[] ptgs = FormulaParser.parse(formula, workbookWrapper, FormulaType.CELL
            , sheet.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(sheet));
    for (Ptg ptg : ptgs) {
        if (ptg instanceof RefPtgBase) // base class for cell references
        {
            RefPtgBase ref = (RefPtgBase) ptg;
            if (ref.isColRelative())
                ref.setColumn(ref.getColumn() + shiftCols);
            if (ref.isRowRelative())
                ref.setRow(ref.getRow() + shiftRows);
        } else if (ptg instanceof AreaPtg) // base class for range references
        {
            AreaPtg ref = (AreaPtg) ptg;
            if (ref.isFirstColRelative())
                ref.setFirstColumn(ref.getFirstColumn() + shiftCols);
            if (ref.isLastColRelative())
                ref.setLastColumn(ref.getLastColumn() + shiftCols);
            if (ref.isFirstRowRelative())
                ref.setFirstRow(ref.getFirstRow() + shiftRows);
            if (ref.isLastRowRelative())
                ref.setLastRow(ref.getLastRow() + shiftRows);
        }
    }
    formula = FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString(workbookWrapper, ptgs);
    dest.setCellFormula(formula);
}
```

I still don't know if I had it correct for all cell formulas, but it works for me, fast and reliable.

Comment: I'm grasping at straws 2 years later, but do you know if there is an NPOI equivalent to setColumn(), setRow(), setFirstColumn(), and setLastColumn()? Or if it was discontinued in recent version of POI / NPOI?

Comment: @justiceorjustus: I know that I'm 6 years late but in NPOI, Row, Column, FirstRow, FirstColumn all have public getter and setter. Because of that you can write ref.Row += shiftRows,...

Answer (score 10):

I too think that there isn't an easy way to do this.

Even the [HSSF and XSSD examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) on the POI site e.g. [TimesheetDemo](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/TimesheetDemo.java) do the formula construction manually. e.g. around line 110

```
String ref = (char)('A' + j) + "3:" + (char)('A' + j) + "12";
cell.setCellFormula("SUM(" + ref + ")");
```

Answer (score 9):

I looked inside *FormulaEvaluator* class and found some POI internal classes that can do the work for us.

FormulaParser, which parses String to array of "parse things":

```
String formula = cell.getCellFormula();
XSSFEvaluationWorkbook workbookWrapper = 
             XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((XSSFWorkbook) workbook);  
/* parse formula */
Ptg[] ptgs = FormulaParser.parse(formula, workbookWrapper, 
             FormulaType.CELL, 0 /*sheet index*/ );
```

ptgs is now our formula in reverse polish notation. Now go through all elements and modify references one by one as you wish:

```
/* re-calculate cell references */
for( Ptg ptg  : ptgs )
    if( ptg instanceof RefPtgBase )    //base class for cell reference "things"
    {
        RefPtgBase ref = (RefPtgBase)ptg;
        if( ref.isColRelative() )
            ref.setColumn( ref.getColumn() + 0 );
        if( ref.isRowRelative() )
            ref.setRow( ref.getRow() + 1 );
    }
```

And you're ready to render "parse things" back to String:

```
formula = FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString(workbookWrapper, ptgs);
cell.setCellFormula( formula );
```

Comment: This one was super helpful and seems to be the easiest way. Two additions:
1) It should be noted that the code uses classes marked as POI internal (e.g. `XSSFEvaluationWorkbook`), so this code might break in later releases.
2) One should also adjust `AreaPtgBase` "things" which describe areas (e.g. `A1:C3`). The code is straight forward based on the handling of `RefPtgBase`shown in this answer.

Comment: I tried the above code and worked on Apache POI 4.1.2. I am yet to handle MAX, MIN cases where a range of cells are used. Thank you @user2622016

Answer (score 5):

Another way to copy formula relatively, tested with poi 3.12

```
public static void copyCellFormula(Workbook workbook, int sheetIndex, int rowIndex, int sourceColumnIndex, int destinationColumnIndex){
    XSSFEvaluationWorkbook formulaParsingWorkbook = XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((XSSFWorkbook) workbook);
    SharedFormula sharedFormula = new SharedFormula(SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
    Row lookupRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
    Cell sourceCell = lookupRow.getCell(sourceColumnIndex);
    Ptg[] sharedFormulaPtg = FormulaParser.parse(sourceCell.getCellFormula(), formulaParsingWorkbook, FormulaType.CELL, sheetIndex);
    Ptg[] convertedFormulaPtg = sharedFormula.convertSharedFormulas(sharedFormulaPtg, 0, 1);
    Cell destinationCell = lookupRow.createCell(destinationColumnIndex);
    destinationCell.setCellFormula(FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString(formulaParsingWorkbook, convertedFormulaPtg));
}
```

Update shared formula as needed:

```
sharedFormula.convertSharedFormulas(sharedFormulaPtg, rowIndexOffset, columnIndexOffset);
```

As of poi 3.12, SharedFormula doesn't support cell reference/formula from other sheets (='Sheet1'!A1). Here's an update to SharedFormula:

```
public class SharedFormula {

    private final int _columnWrappingMask;
    private final int _rowWrappingMask;

    public SharedFormula(SpreadsheetVersion ssVersion) {
        this._columnWrappingMask = ssVersion.getLastColumnIndex();
        this._rowWrappingMask = ssVersion.getLastRowIndex();
    }

    public Ptg[] convertSharedFormulas(Ptg[] ptgs, int formulaRow, int formulaColumn) {
        Ptg[] newPtgStack = new Ptg[ptgs.length];

        RefPtgBase areaNPtg = null;
        AreaPtgBase var9 = null;
        Object ptg = null;
        byte originalOperandClass = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < ptgs.length; ++k) {
            ptg = ptgs[k];
            originalOperandClass = -1;
            if(!((Ptg)ptg).isBaseToken()) {
                originalOperandClass = ((Ptg)ptg).getPtgClass();
            }

            if(ptg instanceof RefPtgBase) {
                if(ptg instanceof Ref3DPxg) {
                    areaNPtg = (Ref3DPxg)ptg;
                    this.fixupRefRelativeRowAndColumn(areaNPtg, formulaRow, formulaColumn);
                    ptg = areaNPtg;
                }else if(ptg instanceof Ref3DPtg) {
                    areaNPtg = (Ref3DPtg)ptg;
                    this.fixupRefRelativeRowAndColumn(areaNPtg, formulaRow, formulaColumn);
                    ptg = areaNPtg;
                }else {
                    areaNPtg = (RefPtgBase)ptg;
                    ptg = new RefPtg(this.fixupRelativeRow(formulaRow, areaNPtg.getRow(), areaNPtg.isRowRelative()), this.fixupRelativeColumn(formulaColumn, areaNPtg.getColumn(), areaNPtg.isColRelative()), areaNPtg.isRowRelative(), areaNPtg.isColRelative());
                }
                ((Ptg)ptg).setClass(originalOperandClass);
            }else if(ptg instanceof AreaPtgBase) {
                if(ptg instanceof  Area3DPxg) {
                    var9 = (Area3DPxg)ptg;
                    this.fixupAreaRelativeRowAndColumn(var9, formulaRow, formulaColumn);
                    ptg = var9;
                }else if(ptg instanceof  Area3DPxg) {
                    var9 = (Area3DPtg)ptg;
                    this.fixupAreaRelativeRowAndColumn(var9, formulaRow, formulaColumn);
                    ptg = var9;
                }else {
                    var9 = (AreaPtgBase)ptg;
                    ptg = new AreaPtg(this.fixupRelativeRow(formulaRow, var9.getFirstRow(), var9.isFirstRowRelative()), this.fixupRelativeRow(formulaRow, var9.getLastRow(), var9.isLastRowRelative()), this.fixupRelativeColumn(formulaColumn, var9.getFirstColumn(), var9.isFirstColRelative()), this.fixupRelativeColumn(formulaColumn, var9.getLastColumn(), var9.isLastColRelative()), var9.isFirstRowRelative(), var9.isLastRowRelative(), var9.isFirstColRelative(), var9.isLastColRelative());
                }
                ((Ptg)ptg).setClass(originalOperandClass);
            }else if(ptg instanceof OperandPtg) {
                ptg = ((OperandPtg)ptg).copy();
            }

            newPtgStack[k] = (Ptg)ptg;
        }

        return newPtgStack;
    }

    protected void fixupRefRelativeRowAndColumn(RefPtgBase areaNPtg, int formulaRow, int formulaColumn){
        areaNPtg.setRow(this.fixupRelativeRow(formulaRow, areaNPtg.getRow(), areaNPtg.isRowRelative()));
        areaNPtg.setColumn(this.fixupRelativeColumn(formulaColumn, areaNPtg.getColumn(), areaNPtg.isColRelative()));
        areaNPtg.setRowRelative(areaNPtg.isRowRelative());
        areaNPtg.setColRelative(areaNPtg.isColRelative());
    }

    protected void fixupAreaRelativeRowAndColumn(AreaPtgBase var9, int formulaRow, int formulaColumn){
        var9.setFirstRow(this.fixupRelativeRow(formulaRow, var9.getFirstRow(), var9.isFirstRowRelative()));
        var9.setLastRow(this.fixupRelativeRow(formulaRow, var9.getLastRow(), var9.isLastRowRelative()));
        var9.setFirstColumn(this.fixupRelativeColumn(formulaColumn, var9.getFirstColumn(), var9.isFirstColRelative()));
        var9.setLastColumn(this.fixupRelativeColumn(formulaColumn, var9.getLastColumn(), var9.isLastColRelative()));
        var9.setFirstRowRelative(var9.isFirstRowRelative());
        var9.setLastRowRelative(var9.isLastRowRelative());
        var9.setFirstColRelative(var9.isFirstColRelative());
        var9.setLastColRelative(var9.isLastColRelative());
    }

    protected int fixupRelativeColumn(int currentcolumn, int column, boolean relative) {
        return relative?column + currentcolumn & this._columnWrappingMask:column;
    }

    protected int fixupRelativeRow(int currentrow, int row, boolean relative) {
        return relative?row + currentrow & this._rowWrappingMask:row;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is. POI would have to parse the formula (taking into account A1 vs. $A$1 vs. $A1 etc.) and I don't believe it has that capacity. When I've done this in the past I've always had to manage this myself. Sorry - not the answer you hoped for!

Answer (score -2):

you can try some third party excel librarys,most of them can handle the relative/absolute range formulas.

Comment: Neither it suggests a concrete library which solves the issue.