# How to copy formula cell with relative reference in Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

All:

I am pretty new to Apache POI, currently when I try to copy formula cell, it can not automatically change relative cell reference, for example:

cell A1 has formula `SUM(A3, B3)`.

In Excel: if I copy that cell to B2, it can automatically be changed to `SUM(B4, C4)`.

In POI: If I copy that formula, it will just copy that formula, without auto change the reference relatively( the cell B2 is still `SUM(A3, B3)` )

I wonder if there is a simple way to do the auto change in POI? Thank.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636759/poi-excel-applying-formulas-in-a-relative-way and my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594254/apache-poi-update-formula-references-when-copying.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks so much.